# No fullscreen in COD Warzone?

Tags: display, fullscreen, framerate

I'm having a major issue with this game, I got 90 fps on average but it displays no more than 30. I also don't have the FULLSCREEN option. I have window and borderless but that is it. If anybody had experienced similar issues or knows how to solve this, help would be seriously appreciated !

Comment: To start with, 1) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and 2) which release number? 3) Have you added STEAM and/or WINE and/or PlayOnLinux, and if so, which package(s)? 4) Was that 90 fps speed in Windows or Linux? Please click [edit] and add that vital information for items 1-4 to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Didnt have the fullscreen option either. What worked for me was to install windows 10, had windows 7 before. Hope it helps